Capture bilinear filtered version of an image from Chrome for use in code
I need to bilinearly filter a (canvas) image for use thereafter in JS code. Chrome already does this filtering as part of their browser tab content rendering, when you scale up the tab content size.
Options
(1) I can do the filtering on the CPU, I have code that does so, but it's wasteful to do so on CPU.
(2) I can write or download a GPU shader to do this for me. This means explicit call out to WebGL or what have you, to do the work.
(3) I can ask Chrome for an already-filtered version of the image, as Chrome would render this if we scale up the tab content.
Question
It's (3) that I've often wondered about. Is it possible? Is there any way to access those data buffers that represent already-rendered images in Chrome, from Javascript? My image changes from run to run (it is generated), so offline approaches aren't going to help.
I'm guessing the answer is "no" from a security perspective, but I'm hoping for a "yes" that doesn't include manual screen grabs.
EDIT: As an aside, you will notice that if you scale up a canvas in Chrome, by default if you copy its content via context menu, and paste that into a paint tool, it will give you the base imageData, not the scaled version. So I have a feeling the scaled image exists only in GPU memory, meaning it's almost certainly off-limits.
